# Scaling precision matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, precision-matrix

I have little knowledge about algebra, and need to rescale a precision(not variance-covariance) matrix. Suppose I have two variables, X1, X2, and their precision matrix is [5, .7, .7, .2]. Because the "variance" of the first variable(X1) should be 1, I thought that I could have such variance by multiplying the precision matrix by .2, but I wanted to confirm with you if this approach is correct.

Also, I am wondering if I need to rescale covariances as well and if so, how to? I don't think I need to take care of the variance of the other variable (X2, that is, .2).

Comment: A consideration of the units in which the precision components are expressed will be an excellent guide towards a correct solution.